# Getting a subset of an sklearn crossvalidation object

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm doing cross-validation on a dataset `X` with three labels `0,1,2`. To get the training and testing indices, I use `scikit-learn`:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
cv = StratifiedKFold(labels, n_folds=5)

for train_idx, test_idx in cv:
    # do my classification
    train_data = X[train_idx]
    train_labels = labels[train_idx]
    # etc..
```

However, I actually only want to do pairwise classifications, so I only ever need the subset of indices that concern labels `0,1`, for example. Unfortunately, I cannot alter the dataset `X`. Is there anyway to modify the `cv` object? I know I could modify the `train_idx` and `test_idx` inside each fold and save them in a separate container, but I'd ideally like to have an `sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold` object for this. Thanks for your help!